# Check if password matches to the current user's password in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have to check if the inputted password matches the password of the current user.

```
class UserPasswordMatchAPIView(APIView):
    """ Check password """

    serializer_class = UserPasswordSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        password = self.request.data.get("password")

        if user.check_password(password):
            return Response(data={"message": True})
        else:
            return Response(data={"message": False})


class UserPasswordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("password",)
```

When I try to run this in swagger, it shows that it has no parameters required. I have to input the password. Is there any way I can execute this?

Comment: if your user model extends `AbstractBaseUser` it should work

Comment: How can I add the request body where I can input the password?

Comment: so you have to add a `post` method and you can post the json body from swagger or postman. you can then input password there

Comment: so you can change the `get` method to `post`

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked now. I'm really still new to Django, thanks for the help!